# Unable to println in scala program

Tags: scala, class, syntax, println

Following scala code shows no output please help me with corrections.I'm new to scala.I am trying to print a Rational class instance.

```
object Test{

    def main() {
        var r = new Rational(2,3)
        println(r)
        println("Hello")
        //println(Rational(2,3).add(Rational(3,3)))
   }

}

class Rational(n:Int,d:Int)
{

    val num:Int =n
    val den:Int =d
    val sum :Int =num+den
    def add(that:Rational):Rational={
        return new Rational(num*that.den+den*that.num,den*that.den)
     }

     override def toString(): String =  num + "/" + den 

}

object Rational {
    def apply(n:Int,d:Int)=new Rational(n,d)
}
```

Comment: don't use return (doesn't solve the problem but still important thing) last expression in the block is the returned value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `def main()` to `def main(args: Array[String])`, the JVM won't recognize a `main` method that doesn't have the right argument type